# If a polynomial $f(x) = (x^{2}-1)q_{1}(x) + (2x-7)$, then $(x+1)f(x/2) = (x^{2}-x-2)q_{2}(x) + (-5x-5)$

Tags: polynomials

If a polynomial $f(x) = (x^{2}-1)q_{1}(x) + (2x-7)$ for some polynomial $q_{1}(x)$, is there a polynomial $q_{2}(x)$ such that 
$$(x+1)f(x/2) = (x^{2}-x-2)q_{2}(x) + (-5x-5)?$$

Comment: Every term in the second equation is divisible by $x+1$, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First calculate $f(x/2)$:
$$f(x/2) = \left( \frac{x^2}{4}-1\right) q_1(x/2) + (x-7)$$
Then
\begin{align*}
(x+1)f(x/2) &= (x+1)\frac{1}{4}(x^2-4) q_1(x/2) + (x+1)(x-7) \\
&= \frac{1}{4}(x+1)(x+2)(x-2)q_1(x/2) + x^2-6x-7 \\
\end{align*}
Notice that $x^2-6x-7 = x^2-x-2 + (-5x-5)$ and $(x+1)(x-2) = x^2-x-2$. So
\begin{align*}
(x+1)f(x/2) &= \frac{1}{4}(x+2)(x^2-x-2)q_1(x/2) + (x^2-x-2) + (-5x-5) \\
&= (x^2-x-2)\left( \frac{1}{4}(x+2)q_1(x/2)+1\right) + (-5x-5)
\end{align*}
Thus
$$q_2(x) = \frac{1}{4}(x+2)q_1(x/2)+1$$